# remove all instances of item from the input array rather than just one

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public static String[] remove(String[] symbols, String c)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++)
 {
  if (symbols[i] == null ? c == null : symbols[i].equals(c))
  {
   String[] copy = new String[symbols.length-1];System.arraycopy(symbols, 0, copy, 0, i);
   System.arraycopy(symbols, i+1, copy, i, symbols.length-i-1);
    return copy;
  }
 }
   return symbols;
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your codes ?

Comment: Thanks Mohit and Suresh, I am trying to remove all instances i-e String c, not only the first one. Can anyone please help me

Comment: What is your issue with the codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove from the array you do not want `i` to increase. You also do not want to return anything until after the loop.

Replace the line

```
return copy;
```

with

```
symbols = copy;
i--;
```

The line `return copy;` makes no sense if you want to continue to remove elements.